Prove that $ (1 + 2x)(1 - y)(1 - z) \geq (1 + 2(xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}})(1 - (xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}})^2 $
I checked on WolframAlpha, and it seems that the inequality $(1 + 2x)(1 - y)(1 - z) \geq (1 + 2(xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}})(1 - (xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}})^2 $ holds true, given the constraints $0 < x \leq 0.5$, $x \geq y \geq z =0$. However, I'm uncertain of how to prove it rigorously. Can you provide a hint or a proof for this inequality?
Here is a link to wolframalpha

Proof.
We have
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS} 
 &= (1 + 2x)(1 - y)(1-z) - 2xyz - 1 + 3(xyz)^{2/3}\\
 &\ge (1 + 2x)(1 - y)(1-z) - 2xyz - 1 + 3yz \tag{1}\\
 &= 2x(1-y-z) + 4yz - y - z\\
 &\ge 2y(1 - y - z) + 4yz - y -z \\
 &= (1 - 2y)(y - z)\\
 &\ge 0
\end{align*}
where we use $(xyz)^{2/3} \ge yz$ in (1).
